# What are Annotations in Java, I am trying to understand but all the information available on Google is very difficult to understand

Tags: java, annotations

I need to understand the purpose of Annotations. I am trying my best to Google it but all the explanations available are very hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation is nothing but information about the code. It is not that complicated, it describes the code that comes after its declaration. 
@Override Example

Suppose you're writing a class that extends another class.

The new class overrides a method of the superclass.

That method can be annotated with the @Override annotation.

If the method is overridden incorrectly, for example, you leave out a parameter in the overridden method, or change the return type, it no longer overrides the superclass's method. If it's annotated with @Override, the compiler will complain and give a compilation error saying that the method *doesn't* override anything.

So in this case the annotation provides a compile-time check to see if what you *intended* is what you actually *implemented*.

You can also create your Custom annotations. Check out this link.

```
http://www.journaldev.com/721/java-annotations-tutorial-with-custom-annotation-example-and-parsing-using-reflection
```